# Failed to find changed memory content in gdb

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, 32-bit, att

I am debugging a `x86` `32bit` binary program. And when I try to execute the instructions below, I just cannot find any memory update in the memory corresponding to `buf` when use `gdb` to debug. ( The `buf` is allocated in `.bss` section).

```
... 
movl $0x4E713,buf(,%eax,0x4)
add $0x1,%eax
...
```

When I execute the above code in `gdb`, I did these:

```
x/10x &buf
```

And to my surprise, even after the execution of the above code, the content of `buf` is still something like this (suppose the value of `eax` is **zero**):

```
0xf7fb6ef0 <buf>:       0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0xf7fb6f00 <buffer>:    0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0xf7fb6f10 <buffer>:    0x00000000      0x00000000
```

Doesn't the address `0xf7fb6ef0` contain value `0x4e713` ?

Am I clear ? Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: It should contain that value. Are you sure `eax` is zero? Sometime during debugging I stop one instruction earlier or later, are you sure you executed the `movl`?

Comment: @knm241, thank you. I double checked the debugging. I am sure `eax` is zero and it has executed the instructions.

Comment: Disassemble the instruction in gdb and verify the address.

Comment: @Jester, Thank you! It works! I found the `buf` variable in address `0x807de68` and successfully found the changed memory. This is really wired..

Comment: @Jester. Could you write a response below? I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the `buf` you see refers to another symbol of the same name, or gdb picks up a wrong address somehow. Disassemble the instruction in gdb, and verify the actual address.

You might also try `info variables ^buf$`